# How to add an existing framework in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to add the AdColony.h frameWork after downloading it, but I can't find it in Xcode 5. I was able to do it in the last version, but can't find it in this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Click on your project in the Project Navigator on the left side. In General go to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". Click on the + button

[image]

and click on "Add Other" and then add the framework you have downloaded.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just wanted to add that I had to switch from Project to Target in order to find the General tab.

Answer (score 16):

Strange. I was just doing the same thing in XCode 5.0.2 and I had to click on the Project, select the *Tests Target, then select *not* the General tab but actually the Build Phases tab to see "Link Binary With Libraries" where I was able to add the framework.

Answer (score 10):

Follow this screen shots

[image]

Run and Go

Comment: Finally. I was searching all the time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I use Xcode 6.4, and I happen to be confronted with the same problem.
I tried many ways suggested by others while none worked.(no button named General as others said)
Here comes my solution.

- Select your project in the project navigator
- Click 'Build Phases' tab
- Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
- Click button '+' to add items

step 1-4

[image]

- Search and choose the frameworks you need, for example, I choose 'OpenGL.framework', and click the button 'Add'

[image]

- Finally, you can see the frameworks you choose in the window

Answer (score 0):

Adding it in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" as other answer discribe did not work for me in xcode 6.4.

However drag and drop it into Frameworks folder (Project Navigator) and creating a reference did worked.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode v11 uses different settings

```
Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content //for app
//or
Frameworks and Libraries //for Framework, extension...
```

here you should decide `embed` or `Do not embed`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687170/do-not-embed-embed-sign-embed-without-signing-what-are-they-what-th/63269154#63269154)

When you drag and drop a framework Xcode automatically adds necessary settings like `Library Search Paths` or `Framework Search Paths`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451861/xcode-6-no-frameworks-folder-in-project-navigator/59216377#59216377)

[[More examples here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331056/library-static-dynamic-or-framework-project-inside-another-project/59216151#59216151)