# Mach-O Linker Error When Adding Unit Tests - XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, ocunit

I'm trying to add OCUnit tests to an existing project (in XCode 4.6.3). I followed the instructions here - http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/ however I'm getting 78 Mach-O errors only when trying to run the tests. I can compile the main target just fine.

One thing to note I have not modified the tests yet, they are just the standard template.  I'm not sure example what I'm doing wrong.

One error message

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_AudioComponentFindNext",
>   referenced from:
>         l651 in libNuanceSpeechAnywhere.a(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
>         l652 in libNuanceSpeechAnywhere.a(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)

Here is a screen shot of a bunch of the errors.

[image]

Comment: Have you included the AudioUnit framework in your test target?  Maybe you only specified it in the dependencies for your application target, but not the test target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `AudioUnit` framework to your project first and then rebuild it.

This is [how you add frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19337932/361247) to your project.

Comment: That seems to work, but I'm confused why it's necessary when my tests are not linking to my application in any way.  Can you explain why this is needed?

Comment: @ansible I'm not completely sure how you structure your tests, but I am guessing that you are using this framework somewhere in the application and the test might be mocking the class that's using that framework. Just a very wild guess.

Comment: Nope, there is only the one default test that just the one default test that asserts failure.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey I'm on iOS 8.1 project right now, it's right there.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo : AudioToolBox, CoreAudioKit and CoreAudio frameworks found in Build Phases that can be added in iOS 8.1.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey Maybe you've added that already? Maybe your error is not the same as OP's error? I can see AudioUnit right here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvncz9ltv1w4ic4/Screenshot%202015-01-12%2020.30.30.png?dl=0

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo : Great!! But why does AudioUnit is not displayed in my case. I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 and OS X 10.10.1 Check this https://www.dropbox.com/s/jcry69v7q5ndfhj/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-12%20at%206.16.24%20pm.png?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

After banging my head against the keyboard for a few hours, I found this solution if you're using CocoaPods:

In your podfile, add your test target as well with the necessary dependencies

```
workspace 'MyProject'

target 'MyProject' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'RealmSwift'

end

target 'MyProjectTests' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'RealmSwift'

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Then just run pod install and everything should end up configured correctly. I recommend running pod install --verbose so you can see if there are any warnings. If you manually edited the build configuration, Pod will complain about it. Follow the recommendation and then reinstall. Works like a charm.