# Installing OpenSSL library for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, static-libraries

I have installed OpenSSL in xcode for receipt validation, but it doesn't work.

I download `openssl.xcodeproj` and `openssl-1.0.1f`. I extract openssl-1.0.1f and add `openssl.xcodeproj` to my project.

[image: files in finder] 
[image: inserted openssl.xcodeproj]

I edit the `Header Search Path` to :

```
 /Users/marko/Documents/Razvoj/BIView\ Mobile\ New\ Version/openssl/include/openssl
```

I added `libcrypto.a` in `Target Dependencies` under Build Phases

and added `libcrypto.a` in `Link Binary With Libraries`

as was described in http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-inclusion-of-openssl-into-iphone-app-projects/.

But when I build project it stops with error :

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/ .... -bmgslnakszsfovecplbzoslykrxo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcrypto.a'
```

Why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add an existing framework in Xcode 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337890/how-to-add-an-existing-framework-in-xcode-5)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> OK, how to build and install it....

It might be easier to use a pre-built version of OpenSSL for iOS. You can find one at this [Github account](https://github.com/noloader). The OpenSSL from that Github are multi-arch. They have ARMv7, ARMv7s, ARM64, and i386. That means they work with devices and simulators.

Download either OpenSSL 1.0.1e or 1.0.1f. Install it in a location like `/usr/local/ssl/ios`.

Then, add the headers to your Xcode project. They are located in `/usr/local/ssl/ios/include`:

[image]

Finally, add the multi-arch libs (`libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a`) to your Xcode project. They are located in `/usr/local/ssl/ios/lib`:

[image]

Comment: in `/usr/local/` I have maps : bin, etc, include, lib, man, Qt, sbin, share, textlive. Do you mean to create new file named `ssl`, but then libcrypto.a and libssl.a would not be there.

Comment: Do a `mkdir -p /usr/local/ssl/ios`. Then you will have it.

Comment: mkdir: /usr/local/ssl/ios: Permission denied

Comment: I would be more than happy if You could show me how to make .a or .framework from .tar.gz because after that I have another lib te extract (asn1c.tar.gz). :D But it this field (and terminal in general) I don't have much experience so be patient and go slow. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: See the various scripts provided with the iOS tarball. That's what I use to build them. `build-all.sh` calls the other scripts in turn for a particular platform. The other scripts set the environment and then invoke `config`, `make`, etc. Your mileage may vary for `asn1c.tar.gz`.

Comment: "... permission denied... " - `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/ssl/ios`.

Comment: I try `build-all-for-ios.sh` but it gives me : `****************************************
sed: Configure: No such file or directory
sed: Makefile.org: No such file or directory
sed: Makefile.org: No such file or directory
sed: Makefile.org: No such file or directory
****************************************
iPhoneSimulator, -i386
CONFIG_OPTIONS=no-asm no-shared --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/ios
build-all-for-ios.sh: line 42: ./config: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
cp: ./libcrypto.a: No such file or directory
. make:***No rule to make target clean.Stop.`

Comment: In the middle is more but I couldn't paste all of it

Comment: You should ask another question since this is different from your original question.

Comment: I posted new question pleas look and answer

Comment: I want to use openssl in swift , but getting error . Please suggest it , How to configured openssl with swift.

Comment: In recent versions of Xcode, putting the location in User Search Path results in errors about using angled brackets instead of quotes for the filenames in #include statements. Do what the answer says, but put the location in Header Search Paths instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the library as a Framework. See this question: [how to add an existing framework in Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337890/how-to-add-an-existing-framework-in-xcode-5).

Its OK to add the OpenSSL libraries under Frameworks. Its how things are done under  Apple/Xcode.

I use the Absolute Path like in the image below because Crypto++, OpenSSL, etc are installed in `/usr/local`. The image below is a screen capture I have handy of Crypto++, and not OpenSSL's `libcrypto.a` or `libssl.a`. But the same applies to all libraries.

[image]

Comment: My problem is that I have openSll.xcodeproj, and openSLL.tar.gz. If I have openSll.framework I would know what to do.

Comment: I don't know what `openSll.xcodeproj` is. `openssl-1.0.N.tar.gz` is the source code. Is that what you have? If so, you need to unpack, build, and install it.

Comment: OK, how to build and install it. I am new at this stuff and I will be really thankfull if you could help me.

Comment: See [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. There's also a bunch of `INSTALL.<platform>` readme's in the root of the source code. The 5 second fly-by: `./config; make all; sudo make install`. You'll then find it in `/usr/local/ssl`.

Comment: in terminal in navigate to file where openssl-1.0.N.tar.gz is located and write your script. It says make: *** [links] Error 1
making all in crypto...
/bin/sh: /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
Password: and I dont know whitch password I should write.

Comment: You have to cross-compile OpenSSL for iOS after setting your environment (my bad, I forgot to mention it). See the answer below.

Comment: I am using openssl in swift , but getting error . Please suggest it , How to configured openssl with swift.