# Cocoapods - how can I make it add iOS frameworks to the project?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

I use Cocoapods to integrate my lib into other projects.
For my lib to work, the hosting application must include other iOS frameworks, such as `SystemConfiguration, CoreTelephony` and an iOS library: `libicucore.tbd`.

My question is, can I add these dependencies to my podspec file so these framework and lib will be added automatically to the hosting application, once my lib is installed via Cocoapods?

I looked for hours and couldn't find the way to do so, or my trials failed.

**ADDITIONS**:

This is what I added to my podspec:

```
  s.frameworks = 'SystemConfiguration', 'CoreTelephony', 'Security'
```

Tried this as well:

```
s.vendored_frameworks = 'SystemConfiguration.framework', 'CoreTelephony.framework', 'Security.framework'
```

I created a test project and added my lib to it using Cocoapods. Lib was added successfully, but the frameworks are not included in the project.

Answer (score -1):

That may not be a case for CocoaPods, if you want to add iOS framework to an iOS Project, there are 2 steps to follow:

1. Link the framework in your targets, check:
   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17
2. Import the framework to the top of your class:
   `import SystemConfiguration`, for example.

Check also this link, there is a very detailed answer:
[how to add an existing framework in Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337890/how-to-add-an-existing-framework-in-xcode)

Good luck.

Comment: your answer has nothing to do with my question. Did you even read the question before replying?

Comment: Yes I did misunderstand your question, just ignore this.